# Nuxt page transition timing

Tags: nuxt.js, gsap

How does nuxt calculate the time before it redirects/switches to the new page between page transitions? I know it's done automatically when defining transitions through CSS however I'm using GSAP for my animation. Will nuxt figure the time by themself or am I required to set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you could find the actual flow of [client-side navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#the-full-navigation-resolution-flow)

1. Navigation triggered.
2. Call beforeRouteLeave guards in deactivated components.
3. Call global beforeEach guards.
4. Call beforeRouteUpdate guards in reused components.
5. Call beforeEnter in route configs.
6. Resolve async route components.
7. Call beforeRouteEnter in activated components.
8. Call global beforeResolve guards.
9. Navigation is confirmed.
10. Call global afterEach hooks.
11. DOM updates triggered.
12. Call callbacks passed to next in beforeRouteEnter guards with instantiated instances.

---

Here are the various steps regarding the [CSS transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Custom-Transition-Classes) in Vue

- enter-class
- enter-active-class
- enter-to-class (2.1.8+)
- leave-class
- leave-active-class
- leave-to-class (2.1.8+)

---

And here are [Nuxt global page transitions](https://github.com/ivodolenc/nuxt-gsap-module#nuxt-global-page-transitions)

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  buildModules: ['nuxt-gsap-module'],

  // Add global page transition
  pageTransition: {
    name: 'page',
    mode: 'out-in',
    css: false,

    beforeEnter(el) {
      this.$gsap.set(el, {
        opacity: 0
      })
    },

    enter(el, done) {
      this.$gsap.to(el, {
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: 'power2.inOut',
        onComplete: done
      })
    },

    leave(el, done) {
      this.$gsap.to(el, {
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: 'power2.inOut',
        onComplete: done
      })
    }
  }
}
```

---

There is no special magic here: just Nuxt using the hooks available for the transitions.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to trigger the enter hook on initial load? It doesn't get triggered when you hard refresh browser or visit it for the first time.

Comment: I recommend a `console.log` to see which navigation guard is triggered or not. It's maybe just a CSS issue, or maybe look if `mode: 'in-out'` is not fixing the issue. I think it's more of a CSS subject here.

Comment: I used console.log() to check but the hook didnt get triggered. Maybe it is just a bug when developing and will work in production mode?

Comment: @KasperÖstberg a [repro] is highly recommended in this case. Otherwise, you can always build it locally yeah, but I'm not sure that this is anyhow related.

Comment: Code for pages/index.vue:
`
<script>
export default {
  ...
  transition: {
    enter(el) {
      console.log('enter', el)
    }
  }
</script>
`

Comment: @KasperÖstberg this is not what I call a [repro]. Do you have a codesandbox or alike?

Comment: sorry about that, I created a sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rgb-1msg3p?file=/pages/index.vue